# Learning JavaME Programming....Confused

Tags: java, java-me

I have just started to try and learn JavaME and I'm quite confused how it works and how to piece it all together.

For my first task i thought a simple application would be the best approach. I want to create an app that lets the user input a word into a TextField() and then press a button or activate a function that sends this input to a server. The server responds by sending back "OK".

This is simple enough because i have written a swing application that can send/recieve data from a tomcat server, all it takes is a MouseListener and an InputStream.

I would now like to make a simple app like that using JavaMe. I cant however work out how. I have created a form with an attached TextField that allows the user to input text and created and an exit button that quits the application.

How would i now go about creating a command that takes the text value from the TextField and opens an InputStream.

Thanks for any help in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpConnection

much info can be found here !

http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html

Comment: Yes, but how would i call this. If using standard java i would just setip a mouseListener.

Say i use a Command, how would i call a function?